# Why do I get "Waiting for wzrd.in..." for a minute?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I am running a firebase project locally with

```
firebase serve
```

However it takes a long time for the initial HTML page to load. I just see this message for about a minute:

> Waiting for wzrd.in...

I have no idea what is going on. I have been away from this project for half a year, but I do not remember seeing something like it before.

Could it be related to this?

> Warning: You're using Node.js v10.15.1 but Google Cloud Functions only supports v6.11.5.

---

EDIT: The corresponding page in the deployed project loads fast.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the problem. This line in the html file:

```
<script src="http://wzrd.in/standalone/uuid%2Fv4@latest"></script>
```

Seems to be related to Browserify which I do not use, but tried to test (half a year ago).